# Extend angular bootstrap confirm directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have to add some application specific functionality to angular bootstrap confirm [directive](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-confirm).

I can easily use it directly in my code but when I try to use it by creating my own directive, I keep on getting module injector error.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=mwlConfirmProvider%20%3C-%20mwlConfirm%20%3C-%20myDirective
```

**Global Declaration**

```
angular.module('myModule',
[
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngSanitize',
    'mwl.confirm'
]);
```

**Directive**

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .directive('myDirective', directive);

directive.$inject = ['mwlConfirm'];

function directive(mwlConfirm) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linkFunction
    };

    function linkFunction(scope, element, attrs) {

          //code removed for brevity
          var confirmOptions = ...
          ...
          ...
          mwlConfirm.value('confirmationPopoverDefaults', confirmOptions);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can't inject directives. Take a look at [Understanding Directives-extending](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives#extending-directives)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can inject directives as a dependency into another directive. You can do this with services and factories, but directives are applied to the DOM.